# Sending files with content-type as application/xml using Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send an XML file to a server using Requests.

The required content-type is application/xml. This however seems not to work properly.

If I read the file as binary (and without encoding), it is the same situation.

The curl command:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data @File.xml --include URL
```

however works perfectly fine.

I tried my best to find some information, but I can't figure it out!

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
with open(fileName, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as inputFile:
    enctype = "application/xml"
    headers = {"Content-Type": enctype}
    payload = {"payload" : inputFile}
    response = requests.post(URL, data = payload, headers = headers)
```